# onActivityResult is not triggered when startActivityForResult from a common method

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I am writing an app which TV and phone layout uses different methods, and they share some common methods. I put the common methods into a separated class. Before I call the common method, "activity" is passed to the common class, and "startActivityForResult" is called from the common method. However, finish() does not trigger the onActivityResult() on the calling "Activity".

MainFragment.kt

```
class MainFragment : BrowseFragment() {
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        TVHandler.activity = activity
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        //not triggered    
    }
}
```

TVHandler.kt

```
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult
class TVHandler{
    fun play(item: Movie, extra_url: String = ""){    
                val intent = Intent(activity, PlaybackActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("item", item)
                intent.putExtra("url", url)
                startActivityForResult(activity, intent, 0, null)
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var activity: Activity
    }
}
```

PlaybackActivity.kt

```
class PlaybackActivity : FragmentActivity() {
    fun channelSwitch(direction: String, showMessage: Boolean){
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putExtra("action", "switch")
        intent.putExtra("direction", direction)
        intent.putExtra("showMessage", showMessage)
        this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

play() is called. Some action triggered ChannelSwitch(). However, onActivityResult() is not triggered. MainActivity is shown, without any error recorded. May I know how to modify it to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `onActivityResult` in your activity that hosts the fragment so it can pass value to your fragment

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Comment: oh it works. but why it works on activity but not in the fragment? it used to work in fragment (before I write the common method in TVHandler.kt)

Comment: even though the fragment is the one making the startActivityForResult() call, the activity gets the first shot at handling the result, so you need to call super to pass the result to fragment